# SOQL Select all columns in Azure Data Factory (Incremental Load from Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory, soql, queryselectall

Azure Data Factory gives an option to load data incrementally by using an SOQL query, Example bellow:

```
Select COLUMN_1,...,COLUMN_N from Account Where COLUMN_X = 'VALUES_X'
```

There is another solution: **Delta copy from a database with a control table**; but it is dedicated to Azure SQL Database and doesn't take into consideration other Data Sources like Salesforce:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table

Thus, we always have to use an SOQL query. The problem with it, is that we can't do a **SELECT ALL** as in SQL, example bellow:

```
Select * from Account
```

So we have to write manually tens of columns for multiple tables!

Is there any way to launch an SOQL query from a **Copy Data Activity** in **Azure Data Factory** without mentioning all the columns?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

A SOQL equivalent of `SELECT *` (`SELECT FIELDS(ALL)`) will become available in the [Spring '21 release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_soql.htm&release=230&type=5).

> Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL) now makes it easy to include pre-defined groupings of fields within a query statement using the new FIELDS() function.

> How: Use FIELDS(ALL), FIELDS(STANDARD), or FIELDS(CUSTOM) in your SELECT statements. For more information, see FIELDS() in the SOQL and SOSL Reference.

Until Spring '21 is released, using hard-coded SOQL queries or dynamically generating them by scripting access to the org's Describe API are the only routes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually in Azure Data Factory they give an option to add an SOQL query, so other options remains impossible.